# Dedupe rules for profiles in civicrm

Tags: profile, duplicate-contacts

Is there any way possible to have dedupe rules specific to particular profiles instead of for whole contact feature?

Example:-

Profile 1:-

- Name
- Email
- Dob
- Gender

Profile 2:-

- Name
- Dob
- Gender

Dedupe Rule 1:- Name AND Dob AND Gender

Above rule is defined which applies to both profiles

how make it specific to Profile 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no inbuilt way for doing this directly for Profiles with CiviCRM.

Event management is the only feature in CiviCRM that I know can do this since you can specify the Profile and the matching rule - not suggesting you have folk sign up to an event purely to achieve this but hey, you could ;-)

For Drupal users, you can build a webform_civicrm form and specify the fields and matching rules to apply and hence get very close to what you are asking for.